# Using Excel to keep track of maintenance services done on machines

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Assume that you buy a caterpillar, and for every 10 hours of work, you need to apply lubricant. For every 100, you need to replace a certain part. For 500 hours, you need to perform any given adjustment. For 1000 hours, you need to have it checked by a technician. The formula/s I need should take into account intervals, because a machine needs lubrication every 10 hours, and any other given service every X amount of hours. I hope I am getting my point across.

At our company we have several machines and each machine requires different services. My aim is to create an excel table wherein I type in the amount of work hours of each machine, and by means of conditional formatting I can tell which service needs to be done ASAP.

I would be greatly thankful to anyone who can help me out with this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What kind of formatting do you need for the data cells? The biggest point is that probably you have to make an IF-statement, like "IF the time passed from the last technician check IS LARGER THAN 1000 THEN blablabla ... "

Comment: I would recommend that you just open up Excel and just start doing it. Make a simple example with two machines, and a few maintenance types, just for the sake of a toy example. I'm sure you can figure it out. I mean, I cannot come to your office to do it for you ...

Comment: This is really an Excel question, not a math question.  You might try posting on some site devoted to Excel. SuperUser seems to be the appropriate stackexchange site..